# Regular expression check C# code not working

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to check if various account numbers are separated by commas in my code. The code looks like following:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(billText);

            string input = billText;
            try
            {
                //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(input);

                string[] accountsToBill;
                if (Regex.IsMatch(input, "\\d{10}[,]")) 
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("commas");

                    string[] arr = input.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
                    {
                        arr[i] = arr[i].Trim();
                    }
                    accountsToBill = arr;
                }
                else if (Regex.IsMatch(input, "\\d{10}[\\s]"))  
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("whitespace");

                    input = Regex.Replace(input, @"\s+", " ");
                    string[] arr = input.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
                    {
                        arr[i] = arr[i].Trim();
                    }
                    accountsToBill = arr;
                }
```

and so on...I have checked input and it's not null but for some reason the code is not going into the first if..the standard input I am using is 10 digit numbers separated by commas.

Comment: Wait a second, each digit is separated by a comma? Or 10 continuos digit are separated by a comma?

Comment: If you want each digit to be separated by a comma, the regex should be: `(\\d,){10}`, although it can be perfectioned to not allow a comma in the end of the string

Comment: If it is chunk of 10 numbers separated by comma(like 1234567890,1234567890 and so on..) then I don't see any error in the above code. It should work fine. Can you check what is the input string you are actually passing to the Regular expression?

Comment: Every number is separated by comma.

Comment: Will someone explain why in world would someone want to close this question??

Comment: Can you post a sample input?

Comment: @nitinsh99: Because it's a poor question. It's just a "why doesn't my code work?". It's hard to know what the real problem is, and there's too much extraneous code. I advise some reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using regex for very simple string checks. They have heavy overheads. I don't see a use of RegEx in the situation you provided. Simple string functions can be used to achieve what you are looking for.

If it doesn't matter which character (comma or space) is the splitter and you want to consider both as split character, then you can easily replace the entire code with one single line:

```
string[] accountsToBill = input.Split(", ".ToCharArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Otherwise, the way you are doing, you can still do without RegEx, by using the `String.Contains` function for comparison:

```
string[] accountsToBill;
if (input.Contains(",")) {
    accountsToBill = input.Split(",".ToCharArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
} else if (input.Contains(" ")) {
    accountsToBill = input.Split(" ".ToCharArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expressions seem to be a bit off.  I've rewritten them.

```
//sample input = 0123456789,0123456789,0123456789
if (Regex.IsMatch(input, @"\d{10},"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("comma");
}
else if (Regex.IsMatch(input, @"\d{10}\s"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("White space");
}
```

Comment: I haven't had my regular dose of caffeine.  Edited the output.